# How do you add the two smallest numbers from an array of numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
  const sorted = numbers.sort((a, b) => {
    a - b;
  });
  return sorted[0] + sorted[1];
}
```

Its a question from code wars. This is my result but its failing one of the tests, where I sorted the array and tried to add the two smallest numbers. Can somone please help?

Comment: possibly because you didn't consider empty array or a single item

Answer (score 1):

Probaby you use array function in wrong way, in this algotithm you must return value a-b inside sort function

```
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
  const sorted = numbers.sort((a, b) => {
    return a - b;
  });
  return sorted[0] + sorted[1];
}
```

or

```
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
  const sorted = numbers.sort((a, b) =>  a - b);
  return sorted[0] + sorted[1];
}
```